# QTreeWidget Collaps/Expand items

Tags: qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

In QtCreator I added a Tree Widget with two columns to my canvas. This created the XML as follows:-

```xml
 <widget class="QTreeWidget" name="postgresTree">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>20</x>
           <y>10</y>
           <width>851</width>
           <height>471</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true"/>
         </property>
         <property name="lineWidth">
          <number>1</number>
         </property>
         <property name="allColumnsShowFocus">
          <bool>false</bool>
         </property>
         <property name="columnCount">
          <number>2</number>
         </property>
         <column>
          <property name="text">
           <string notr="true">Schema</string>
          </property>
         </column>
         <column>
          <property name="text">
           <string notr="true">Table</string>
          </property>
         </column>
```

I then populated this with:-

```cpp
  QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata");

    while(query.next()) {
        QString schema = query.value(0).toString();

        QTreeWidgetItem *schema_branch = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->postgresTree);
        schema_branch->setText(0,schema);
        schema_branch->setText(1,QString("Table"));

        //Get table list for schema
        QSqlQuery table_query;
        table_query.exec(QString("SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables where schemaname = '%1'").arg(schema));
        while(table_query.next()) {
            QString table = table_query.value(0).toString();
            QTreeWidgetItem *table_branch = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->postgresTree);
            table_branch->setText(1,table);
            schema_branch->addChild(table_branch);
        }

        ui->postgresTree->addTopLevelItem(schema_branch);
    }
```

This works but gives me a fixed layout in my tree without the expand/collapse handles. I want to be able to view this tree with the tables column collapsed and expand/collapse controls showing. How do I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing table_branch to take schema_branch as the parent.

```
QTreeWidgetItem *table_branch = new QTreeWidgetItem(schema_branch);
```

Then you also won't need to call addChild.

Calling addTopLevelItem might not be necessary either because you are already giving the tree itself as the parent which should be sufficient.

```
ui->postgresTree->addTopLevelItem(schema_branch);
```